# Parse json from url android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am trying to parse json from url but I am getting an error. My activity´s code is like that:

```
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Create a progressdialog
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity.this);
                // Set progressdialog title
                //mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
                // Set progressdialog message
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Ké se kuece hoy...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                // Show progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // Create an array

                try {
                    // Locate the array name in JSON
                    //if(jsonobject == null) 

                // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
                    jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                        .getJSONfromURL("http://www.my.url/file.json");



                    preversion_dos = jsonobject.getJSONObject("results");

                    version_definitiva_url = preversion_dos.getString(TAG_VERSION);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {


                 TextView dos=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dos);
                 dos.setText(version_definitiva_url);
                 mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
```

My JSON Fuctions code is like that:

```
public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jArray = null;

        // Download JSON data from URL
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {

            jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }
```

This json I do programmatically like this:

```
 sBuffer = new StringBuffer();
         a= "{\"results\":[{\"version\":\""+version+"\"}]}";
         appendEscaped(sBuffer, a);
         System.out.println(sBuffer);

        private static void appendEscaped( StringBuffer sBuffer, String str) {
            char [] strChars = str.toCharArray();
            for ( char c : strChars ) {
                if ( c >= ' ' && c <= '~' && c != '/') {
                    // Character is ASCII, append as is
                    sBuffer.append(c);
                } else {
                    sBuffer.append(String.format("\\u%04x", (int)c));
                }
            }
        }
```

And the error log that I get is like this, it says that cannot be converted to JSONObject:

```
01-22 01:37:41.126: E/log_tag(4844): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-22 01:37:41.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4844): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-22 01:37:41.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4844): Process: com.iea.eee, PID: 4844
01-22 01:37:41.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4844): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-22 01:37:41.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4844):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
01-22 01:37:41.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4844):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
01-22 01:37:41.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4844):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
01-22 01:37:41.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4844):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
01-22 01:37:41.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4844):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-22 01:37:41.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4844):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-22 01:37:41.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4844):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-22 01:37:41.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4844):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
01-22 01:37:41.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4844): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONObject org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
01-22 01:37:41.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4844):     at com.iea.kesekuece.Comprobador$DownloadJSON.doInBackground(Comprobador.java:209)
01-22 01:37:41.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4844):     at com.iea.kesekuece.Comprobador$DownloadJSON.doInBackground(Comprobador.java:1)
01-22 01:37:41.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4844):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
01-22 01:37:41.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4844):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-22 01:37:41.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4844):     ... 4 more
01-22 01:37:41.362: E/WindowManager(4844): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.iea.eee.Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{3a1fdc61 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,348} that was originally added here
01-22 01:37:41.362: E/WindowManager(4844):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
01-22 01:37:41.362: E/WindowManager(4844):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:271)
01-22 01:37:41.362: E/WindowManager(4844):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
01-22 01:37:41.362: E/WindowManager(4844):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
01-22 01:37:41.362: E/WindowManager(4844):  at com.iea.kesekuece.Comprobador$DownloadJSON.onPreExecute(Comprobador.java:194)
01-22 01:37:41.362: E/WindowManager(4844):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:591)
01-22 01:37:41.362: E/WindowManager(4844):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:539)
01-22 01:37:41.362: E/WindowManager(4844):  at com.iea.kesekuece.Comprobador.onCreate(Comprobador.java:76)
01-22 01:37:41.362: E/WindowManager(4844):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
01-22 01:37:41.362: E/WindowManager(4844):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
01-22 01:37:41.362: E/WindowManager(4844):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
01-22 01:37:41.362: E/WindowManager(4844):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420)
01-22 01:37:41.362: E/WindowManager(4844):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
01-22 01:37:41.362: E/WindowManager(4844):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
01-22 01:37:41.362: E/WindowManager(4844):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-22 01:37:41.362: E/WindowManager(4844):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-22 01:37:41.362: E/WindowManager(4844):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)
01-22 01:37:41.362: E/WindowManager(4844):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-22 01:37:41.362: E/WindowManager(4844):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-22 01:37:41.362: E/WindowManager(4844):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
01-22 01:37:41.362: E/WindowManager(4844):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not getting `JSON` response, as you can see it in `logcat` also you are getting some tags `<html><body><script`

```
data org.json.JSONException: Value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Answer (score 0):

Its JavaScript Error what I am getting.

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script>
    <script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f
        <d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("c7e81067624ba31b7ca1a73062e4ca4a");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; document.cookie="referrer="+escape(document.referrer); location.href="http://kese.260mb.net/hola/version.json?ckattempt=1";
        </script>
        <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tested in [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en), If i open this link directly in chrome (java script enabled) it will work perfect but I use POSTMAN to run where Java Script Error occurred.

You have to check error about **JavaScript** which is enabled or not.

Comment: Do you use [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) Try to use this. you will see error.

Answer (score 0):

I think file json have problem.

- view-source:my.url/file.json it maybe have other html tags.
- copy all content file json and paste json.parser.online.fr to check struct json.

and why don't you use Volley library parse json, it easy and fast.